# Reset slow_log tables in RDS of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I enabled the slow_log_query in RDS in AWS. I want to reset the table but i am getting Access denied in PhpMyadmin while truncating . Any Idea to make it possible .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got a solution

Amazon RDS will not give you SSH access to its database server. That means you don’t have the opportunity to view any of the log files, even the slow query log, for the database. But RDS provides a way to play with the slow queries.

If your slow queries are many then this table will hold too many queries to handle. You cannot truncate the table or delete any row from there. There is only a way to move all the data from this table to another table named ‘slow_log_backup’, making the slow_log table empty.
To do so you have to run a stored procedure already available in RDS.

Select the ‘mysql’ database and you can see some stored procedure listed. Run the procedure named ‘rds_rotate_slow_log’ by running **`CALL mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log`** command.

In the back-end RDS just renames those two tables, it does not actually move the data. Running the command twice will delete the slow log completely from the database server.

Comment: works like a charm :)

Comment: You Saved my day - > Thanksjohnsampson

Comment: The funny thing is that I can run this procedure on read-only connection. So looks like a dangerous feature